# ANR cada que la aplicación regresa de segundo plano despues de varios segundos

Tags: java, android, android-layout, activity, kotlin

Me pasa solamente en un Motorola G5 plus. Ya probé la app en otros celulares y funciona correctamente.
El error pasa cada que corro la app y doy click al botón de HOME o cuando otra aplicación está por arriba de la mia y al retornar a la aplicación la pantalla se pone totalmente en negro y después aparece el ARN.

```
02-06 14:04:02.638 2400-2506/? E/ActivityManager: ANR in com.oomovil.sidecar (com.oomovil.sidecar/.principal.Principal)
PID: 23934
Reason: Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)
Load: 5.05 / 4.87 / 4.63
CPU usage from 0ms to 5428ms later (2018-02-06 14:03:57.169 to 2018-02-06 14:04:02.597):
102% 23934/com.oomovil.sidecar: 101% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 1249 minor 33 major
 24% 2400/system_server: 14% user + 9.9% kernel / faults: 3983 minor 274 major                                                    
4.9% 2860/com.android.systemui: 3.6% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 2618 minor 204 major
4.9% 10158/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor: 3.6% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 2033 minor 280 major
4.7% 2998/com.android.phone: 3.6% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 1847 minor 196 major
  4% 6986/net.zedge.android:remote: 1.8% user + 2.2% kernel / faults: 2427 minor 1012 major
2.7% 143/kswapd0: 0% user + 2.7% kernel
2.2% 2971/com.motorola.process.system: 1.6% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 1516 minor 118 major 
2.2% 3424/.dataservices: 1.4% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 1626 minor 212 major
2.2% 3476/com.motorola.modemservice: 1.6% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 1362 minor 135 major
  0% 2985/com.motorola.actions: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2837 minor 414 major
1.4% 330/mmc-cmdqd/0: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
  0% 3450/com.fingerprints.serviceext: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1676 minor 224 major
1.2% 542/surfaceflinger: 1.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 166 minor
  0% 3463/com.motorola.process.slpc: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1339 minor 218 major
1.2% 11745/kworker/u16:6: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
1.1% 1845/audioserver: 0.5% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 19 minor 3 major
  0% 3437/com.motorola.frameworks.singlehand: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2633 minor 220 major
  0% 434/debuggerd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 295 minor 37 major
0.7% 7/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.7% kernel
0.7% 22269/adbd: 0.3% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 118 minor
0.5% 432/logd: 0.3% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1 minor
0.3% 10/rcuop/0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
0.3% 53/rcuop/6: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
0.3% 7088/osmcore: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 23 minor
0.1% 39/rcuop/4: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
0.1% 46/rcuop/5: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
0.1% 60/rcuop/7: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
0.1% 323/cfinteractive: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
  0% 360/kworker/0:1H: 0% user + 0% kernel
0.1% 376/kworker/4:1H: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
0.1% 1654/irq/45-408000.q: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
0.1% 1854/netd: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 17 minor
0.1% 1978/msm_irqbalance: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1 minor
0.1% 2824/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 18 minor
0.1% 4220/com.android.bluetooth: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 47 minor 14 major
0.1% 5843/com.motorola.motocare: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 53 minor
0.1% 19172/com.microsoft.office.outlook: 0.1% user + 0% kernel / faults: 56 minor
0.1% 22410/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 1 minor
0.1% 24121/kworker/u16:4: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
0.1% 24572/kworker/0:0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
 25% TOTAL: 18% user + 4.9% kernel + 1.2% iowait + 0% softirq
CPU usage from 4536ms to 5071ms later (2018-02-06 14:04:01.705 to 2018-02-06 14:04:02.240):
100% 23934/com.oomovil.sidecar: 100% user + 0% kernel / faults: 5 minor
100% 23934/oomovil.sidecar: 100% user + 0% kernel
 11% 2400/system_server: 3.7% user + 7.4% kernel / faults: 117 minor
7.4% 2506/ActivityManager: 1.8% user + 5.6% kernel
3.7% 2781/InputDispatcher: 3.7% user + 0% kernel
4.3% 6986/net.zedge.android:remote: 1.4% user + 2.9% kernel / faults: 17 minor
5.8% 6986/.android:remote: 1.4% user + 4.3% kernel
2.9% 7088/osmcore: 1.4% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 23 minor
1.2% 1845/audioserver: 1.2% user + 0% kernel
1.2% 21660/AudioIn_946: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
1.8% 10158/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor: 1.8% user + 0% kernel / faults: 54 minor
1.4% 11745/kworker/u16:6: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
 16% TOTA 02-06 14:04:02.651 2400-2506/? I/ActivityManager: Skipping duplicate ANR:
ProcessRecord{67d61c9 23934:com.oomovil.sidecar/u0a201} Input dispatching timed out (Waiting because no window has focus but there is a focused application that may eventually add a window when it finishes starting up.)
```

Al decir botón HOME, me refiero al físico del celular. Y si, en teoria es cuando entra en el onResume() pero es una Activity vacía, no contiene nada ni carga nada, solo onCreate()

```
class Principal : AppCompatActivity() {
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_principal)
     }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.oomovil.sidecar">

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:name=".general.BaseApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".principal.Principal"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".principal.fragments.ActivityServicioDetalle"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

Splash: Esta clase solo es un presentador del logo con animación.

```
    class Splash : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash)

        img_logo.rotateAndScale(true)
    }

    override fun onPostCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Handler().postDelayed({
            startActivity(Intent(this@Splash, Principal::class.java))
            this@Splash.finish()
        }, 3_000)
    }
}
```

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en inglés. El idioma oficial de este sitio es español. Te sugiero revises la guía para realizar preguntas : [ask]

Comment: Aun no puedo cambiar el título. Pero puedes ayudarme?

Comment: Claro que si Jassiel, aquí todos podemos ayudarte solo agrega datos y se más especifico, agrega que hace tu aplicación, además revisa el LogCat la parte donde dice "Caused by" ya que lo que agregas no indica nada

Comment: Ya la edité. Y lo raro es que solo me pasa en un solo dispositivo y nunca me muestra el "Caused by:". Para poder ver el error tengo que cambiar el filtro del Log de "Show only selected application" a "No filters"

Comment: Eso es todo lo que hace, solo abro otra aplicación mientras la mia sigue "viva" y al momento de retornar a ella sale el ARN. Eso es todo, no me dice porque ni nada, ya hice debug y no entra ni pasa el onCreate()

Comment: En el caso del LogCat debes usar la opción " "Show only selected application"" Para que solo muestre el problema en tu aplicación.

Comment: Agrega tu AndroidManifest y las clases que usas con eso será suficiente.

Comment: Ya puedes verlo, la verdad es algo que no entiendo, porque es una simple llamada a otra actividad vacía.

Comment: Cuando estas en la vacia, la mandas a background y regresas es cuando marca error? En verdad es extraño, puede ser algo sencillo pero por eso es importante el LogCat, trata reiniciando tu Android Studio y reconstruyendo el proyecto.

Comment: Es que la verdad no se si es un bug de Android Studio, porque recree el mismo proyecto en mi casa (desde cero) y funciona correctamente. Pero lo vuelvo a hacer en el trabajo y me da este error. Ya volví a hacer el proyecto, ya restauré Android y nada...